# Sprit se difumina mientras lo muevo

Tags: python, pygame

**Ultimamente me estoy interesando por pygame y me gustaria aprender a mover sprites con el teclado,por lo que he estado aprendiendo sobre eso buscando tutoriales en internet.
Funcionaba bien excepto por un detalle,el sprit quando lo movia se difuminaba.
He probado con bajar los fps,subir los fps,quitar algunas opciones claves y nada funciona.
Gracias de antemano y espero que alguien mas experimentado sea capaz de ver mi error.**

````
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600), pygame.RESIZABLE)

pygame.display.set_caption('Gameplay')

imagen=pygame.image.load("fondo.JPG")
fondo=pygame.transform.scale(imagen, (ancho_desado, alto_deseado))


screen.blit(fondo,(0,0)) 
class Jugador(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # Sprite del jugador
    def __init__(self):
        # Heredamos el init de la clase Sprite de Pygame
        super().__init__()
        # Rectángulo (jugador)
        global imagenes
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Leonidas.JPG").convert()
        self.image=pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (100, 100))
        imagenes=self.image
        # Obtiene el rectángulo (sprite)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # Centra el rectángulo (sprite)
        self.rect.center = (ANCHO // 2, ALTO // 2)
        self.velocidad_x = 0
    def update(self):
        # Actualiza esto cada vuelta de bucle.
        if self.rect.top > ALTO:
           self.rect.bottom = 0
        teclas = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if teclas[pygame.K_a]:
           self.velocidad_x = -10
        if teclas[pygame.K_d]:
           self.velocidad_x = 10
        self.rect.x += self.velocidad_x
        if self.rect.right > ANCHO:
            self.rect.right = ANCHO
        self.velocidad_x = 0
# Limita el margen izquierdo
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
jugador = Jugador()
sprites.add(jugador)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
jugando=True
while jugando:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        
        sprites.update()
        sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update() # update the screen

        clock.tick(60)```
````

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que no es un efecto programado?

Comment: Gracias investigando descubrir que es un fallo de como coloque el fondo de mi juego.Muchas gracias